# Setting the value of a UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I have one UITextField which will display some value like "rocky". If I delete this text from the text field then I want the fields text to immediately change back to the original text.

Comment: Is it some kind of placeholder text that you want? I don't really get what you mean.

Comment: thomas i dont want to display on placeholder i want to display on textfield.text not in placeholder

Comment: Then why don't you just use a label?

Answer (score 1):

You need a small change see my answer :

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
if([newString isEqualToString:@""]){
    textField.text=@"rocky";
    return NO;
}

return YES;
```

}

You can notice the difference.Just return NO for your empty string case.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    if(newString.length==0) {
        txtProjectName.text=@"rocky";
        textField.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: hi UnKnow it is working but when i delete text display name rock instead of rocky alway the last character is delete

Comment: UnKnown i want to delete all name rocky then i want display is not alow to change the diffrent name

Comment: sorry i not give u proper message i want .if user delete rocky from textfield then we writen code as par ur answer it will appear again same name rocky on textfield it is right.but i want it is possible can we allow to user to change ther name rocky from other name .If he or see not change any diffrent name then older name rocky should display

Answer (score 0):

Intially add **NSString *strName** as class object.in viewDidLoad add this

```
  strName = @"Rocky";
```

Now

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   if([[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                                    withString:@""] isEqualToString:@""]){
     textField.text=strName;
    }
    else
    {
      strName = text; //change name here for keeping record
    }
    return YES; 
}
```

Comment: hi Prince it is working but when i delete text display name rock instead of rocky alway the last character is delete

Comment: i want if i delete rocky full then full name rocky should be display on textfield it display only rock after delete

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField.length==0) {
        txtProjectName.text=@"rocky";
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Try this.